# Does any one know the optimal solution to solve the following issue in kibana 7.2?

Tags: elasticsearch

> Error : [enhanced_table_visualization] > Request to Elasticsearch
> failed:
> {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"circuit_breaking_exception","reason":"[request]
> Data too large, data for [<agg [16]>] would be [249422016/237.8mb],
> which is larger than the limit of
> [249416908/237.8mb]","bytes_wanted":249422016,"bytes_limit":249416908,"durability":"TRANSIENT"}]

Situation details: I am trying to retrieve data from the enhanced table, If more documents are matched in the given time range it is showing an error like above.

Resource I read: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/circuit-breaker.html

Comment: did you get a chance to go through my answer? let me know if you need more info

Comment: @Laksmi, it been some time, would be great if you can follow up and let me know if you have follow up questions

Answer (score 0):

**Cause**

You are getting this exception because your request exhausted the default circuit breaker for a request, that is 60% of JVM configured in your elasticsearch nodes.

Please refer [request level circuit breaker](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/circuit-breaker.html#request-circuit-breaker) doc for more details.

**Solution:**

As shown in the exception message, request which is exhausting the circuit breaker limit involves the aggregation (which are known to be memory intensive).you can do below things

1. Improve the logic of aggregation so that it consumes less memory by following [this](https://alexmarquardt.com/how-to-tune-elasticsearch-for-aggregation-performance/) and [this](https://www.elastic.co/blog/improving-the-performance-of-high-cardinality-terms-aggregations-in-elasticsearch) blog.
2. You can also increasing the request level circuit breaker limit from 60% to higher limit and fine tune it further.
3. Increase the JVM of your elasticsearch process which will in turn increase the absolute value of CB memory.